# Can BDD be done "after"?

Tags: testing, tdd, bdd

Unit testing is a practice of writing code tests. TDD is the practice of writing them "before". BDD is the practice of writing behavior/spec driven tests.  Can I write BDD "after" or do I have to do it always "before"?

If you write BDD "after", and it's not BDD, then what it is called?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By definition of Behaviour Driven Development, you cannot write the behaviour tests after the code, however that does not mean that doing so isn't useful. You may get more benefit from writing the spec tests first, but they are still useful as regression system tests for your application. So while you're technically not practicing BDD, writing these tests is a good idea. One of the big perks of BDD is that it guides the development of the particular behaviour, so you are losing a lot of value by adding them later, but they still serve some use.

This is the same as writing unit tests after the code in TDD. It's technically not TDD, but having the tests is obviously still useful.

Comment: What it is called then if not BDD?

Comment: Regular development with Behaviour/Spec tests. :P

Comment: You can still do BDD just by having conversations and testing manually. Automation's very useful, for sure, but it's nowhere near as important as having the conversations. BDD was just intended to help developers have those conversations and carry the language into the code. Please don't fixate on the automation!

Comment: This is not just regression-proofing, necessarily. Ex-post behavior specification also serves as a documentation of intended behavior, something that lives at the core of BDD. 
However, there is a conflict with the "driven" part of BDD - this specification didn't steer development unless it was used to e.g. implement the outcome of a behavioral review that resulted in new spec.

Answer (score 3):

Behavior-Driven Development (BDD) is a variation of Test-Driven Development (TDD) and just like with TDD you should write your tests first.

Some people call BDD for TDD done right, or the way it was intended. Also, you could say that BDD is a mix of Domain-Driven Development (DDD) and TDD.

Answer (score 1):

BDD after development is not BDD, and it is a case of validation rather than specification.

However as the other guys mentioned, it does not mean that adding in an acceptance test suite after-the-fact has no value. You will be building a suite of regression acceptance tests that validate behaviour, before proceeding with further development (large refactoring jobs or new features being added).

From experience I would say if you are to do this task, it is best that the key developers who wrote the production code stay well away from writing the acceptance tests (hopefully in the form of Gherkin scripts); and those that are writing them go back to the original requirements documentation (if any) and most definitely collaborate with some of the stakeholders in doing so. This will help make sure that the acceptance tests you write are closer to specification.

Answer (score 1):

I like the observation that BDD-After is simply a case of writing validation.  I also appreciate the comments that a developer doing BDD-After misses some of the other benefits of BDD-As-You-Go.  One point that seems worth adding is that writing a secenario/test before the implementation and then having the test pass is also a type of validation that the test itself is sound.  Writing a passing test for a feature that already works (BDD-After) may leave a developer wondering if their test will "fail appropriately" should a feature get broken.